# Expected squared difference between between the ML estimator and the posterior expectation.

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian, probability-limit-theorems, maximum-likelihood

> Let $\theta$ be a random parameter with support $[0,1]$ and positive density, and let $X_1,X_2,\ldots ~ \rm N(\theta,1)$ be its i.i.d. observations. Does
> $$ \rm E\Big[n\cdot \Big(\hat \theta_n(X_1,\ldots, X_n) - \rm E[\theta| X_1,\ldots, X_n] \Big)^2\Big],$$
> where $\hat\theta_n(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ is the maximum likelihood estimator and $\rm E[\theta| X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ is the Bayesian MSE estimator,
> converge to 0 as $n\to \infty$?

I can show that $n\Big(\hat \theta_n(X_1,\ldots, X_n) - \rm E[\theta| X_1,\ldots, X_n] \Big)^2$ converges to 0 a.s., but it does not yet follow that its expectation should converge to 0 as well.

Is there any well-known theorem that could be readily applied to prove the claim?

Comment: @NN2 Are you sure?  What happens with $P(X_n=0)=1-\frac1{n^2}$  and $P(X_n=2^n)=\frac1{n^2}$ ? I would have thought $X_n \to 0$ almost surely but $\lim E[|X_n-0|^r] =  \infty$.  This question is slightly different as $\theta$ is bounded

Comment: @Henry You are right.